# How do I change string indices to integers in this program?

Tags: python, stock, yahoo-finance, indices, yfinance

I am trying to call on yfinance to get the top 50 holdings of QQQ to run some back testing. However, everytime I run this portion of the code i get the same error saying: **"TypeError: string indices must be integers"**

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

# QQQ ETF symbol
etf_symbol = "QQQ"

# Retrieve the top 50 holdings of the ETF
qqq = yf.Ticker(etf_symbol)
top_50_holdings = qqq.info.get("holdings")[:50]
top_50_symbols = [holding.get("symbol") for holding in top_50_holdings]
```

Can someone please help with as I do not understand how to fix it.

thankyou

I expected to get the top weighted stocks according to yahoo finance but I think because the ticker symbols are strings its causing a massive halt.

Comment: i do `pip install yfinance` and run the code and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you **didn't install Yfinance correctly** :
I install and use your code it worked.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

# QQQ ETF symbol
etf_symbol = "QQQ"

# Retrieve the top 50 holdings of the ETF
qqq = yf.Ticker(etf_symbol)
top_50_holdings = qqq.info.get("holdings")[:50]
top_50_symbols = [holding.get("symbol") for holding in top_50_holdings]

print("TOP 50 HOLDING :" ,top_50_holdings)
print("TOP 50 SymBols :", top_50_symbols)
```

**and this is an answer:**

> TOP 50 HOLDING : [{'symbol': 'AAPL', 'holdingName': 'Apple Inc',
> 'holdingPercent': 0.11270001}, {'symbol': 'MSFT', 'holdingName':
> 'Microsoft Corp', 'holdingPercent': 0.1011}, {'symbol': 'AMZN',
> 'holdingName': 'Amazon.com Inc', 'holdingPercent': 0.0779}, {'symbol':
> 'GOOG', 'holdingName': 'Alphabet Inc Class C', 'holdingPercent':
> 0.0419}, {'symbol': 'FB', 'holdingName': 'Facebook Inc Class A', 'holdingPercent': 0.0404}, {'symbol': 'TSLA', 'holdingName': 'Tesla
> Inc', 'holdingPercent': 0.039}, {'symbol': 'GOOGL', 'holdingName':
> 'Alphabet Inc Class A', 'holdingPercent': 0.0387}, {'symbol': 'NVDA',
> 'holdingName': 'NVIDIA Corp', 'holdingPercent': 0.0378}, {'symbol':
> 'PYPL', 'holdingName': 'PayPal Holdings Inc', 'holdingPercent':
> 0.023}, {'symbol': 'ADBE', 'holdingName': 'Adobe Inc', 'holdingPercent': 0.0215}]
> TOP 50 SymBols : ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'AMZN',
> 'GOOG', 'FB', 'TSLA', 'GOOGL', 'NVDA', 'PYPL', 'ADBE']

To check if your libraries work or install correctly, Please once again try to install from the terminal with this :

```
pip3 install yfinance
```

or

```
pip install yfinance
```

the docs are here:
https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/

Comment: I reinstalled everything and It still didn't work for me.